# Runserver trouble with debugtools

Tags: python

all!
I have recent download source of python project and run server :

```
python manage.py runserver
```

but it shows error

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/kata/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kata/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/kata/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/kata/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/kata/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kata/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/kata/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/kata/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debugtools'
```

Next, i run install module :

```
pip install debugtools
```

Install success.
But, it still error on runserver.
I took all day to research about this but it has not solution.
Please help me how to fix it ! Many thanks all!

Comment: have you installed all requirements ? and check dev env ?

Comment: @sahasrara62 I installed all module in requirement.txt and commands RUN pip... in Dockerfile. 
P/S : run with docker is ok, but it is slow on adapt to screen. So, i want run directly, not run on docker.

Comment: then you need to also install package outside of docker